# Custom cibil score indicator or guage(with indicator) with some animation effect in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, animation

i want to build some UI with some animation effect. So the use case is when we click on middle portion our indicator and gradient color is move and show random value

[I want to build this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwVtZ.png)

[This one i have already build with animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnQZy.png)

here I'm adding some of part of my code

`      class CustomCircularProgress extends CustomPainter {
final double value;

```
  CustomCircularProgress({required this.value});

  @override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

canvas.drawArc(
  Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 170, height: 170),
  vmath.radians(140),
  vmath.radians(260),
  false,
  Paint()
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..color = Colors.black12
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
    ..strokeWidth = 20,
);

const Gradient gradient = SweepGradient(
  startAngle: 1.25 * math.pi / 2,
  endAngle: 5.1 * math.pi / 2,
  tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
  colors: <Color>[
    Colors.red,
    Colors.yellow,
    Colors.green,
  ],
);
canvas.drawArc(
  Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 170, height: 170),
  vmath.radians(140),
  vmath.radians(260 * value),
  false,
  Paint()
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
    ..shader = gradient
        .createShader(Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height))
    ..strokeWidth = 20,
);

// Draw the percentage value in the center
final textStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24);
final textPainter = TextPainter(
  text: TextSpan(text: '${(value * 1000).toInt()}%', style: textStyle),
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
);
textPainter.layout();
final textCenter = Offset(
    center.dx - textPainter.width / 2, center.dy - textPainter.height / 2);
textPainter.paint(canvas, textCenter);
}

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

`
So above code show the circular shape with text value and for animation i just use the animation controller and forward it.

`
late AnimationController controller;

```
       @override
       void initState() {
         controller = AnimationController(
           vsync: this,
           duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
         )..addListener(() {
             setState(() {});
           });
         controller.forward();
         super.initState();
       }
     
       @override
       void dispose() {
         controller.dispose();
         super.dispose();
       }
     
       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Scaffold(
           appBar: AppBar(
             title: Text(widget.title),
           ),
           body: Center(
             child: CustomPaint(
               painter: CustomCircularProgress(value: controller.value),
             ),
           ),
         );
       }
     }`
```

basically this i have tried already anyone please help me to build this